# quantile vs quartile in lay terms

Tags: d3.js, statistics, quantile

My limited understanding is quantile and quartile are some sort of similar but totally different ways of measurement. I googled but could not find an easy to understand explanation. There is a [D3 related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975063/d3-quantile-or-quartile-scale-given-the-quartile-values) but no answer yet.

My specific question is when we should use quantile instead of quartile or vice versa? I appreciate for any lay term explanation or trivial example. Thanks!

Comment: On the border of the scope of this site; you might get better answers on one of the sister SE sites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *cumulative density function* gives you the probability of a random variable being on or below a certain value.

The *quantile function* is the opposite of that. i.e. you give it a probability and it tells you the random variable value.

So the *median* is the value of the quantile at the probability value of 0.5.

A *quartile* is the value of the quantile at the probabilities 0.25, 0.5 and 0.75.

So, in general, you can use the *quantile*. The *quartile* is a special case.

Answer (score 3):

From Wikipedia:

Quantiles are values taken at regular intervals from the inverse of the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of a random variable. Dividing ordered data into q essentially equal-sized data subsets is the motivation for q-quantiles; the quantiles are the data values marking the boundaries between consecutive subsets.

The 4-quantiles are called quartiles.